# How can one determine the members of a C struct in a header file?

Tags: c, struct, header-files

I'm using minGW-W64 compiler and cannot find documentation on functions of `dirent.h` and want to know what members are in the `dirent` struct used in `readdir`, as in the code example below.

In minGW-W64, compiling fails because there is not a `d_type` in the `ep` struct.

My understanding is that there is no way to print all the members of a struct without knowing them in advance, as one can do with object properties in JavaScript.

Can I look it up some how in the compiler files?

Thank you.

```
int
main (void)
{
  DIR *dp;

  struct dirent *ep;
  struct stat *info;

  dp = opendir ("./SQLite3/");

  if (dp != NULL)
    {
      while (ep = readdir (dp))
        {
          printf( "Name : %s, type : %s\n", ep->d_name, ep->d_type );
        }
      (void) closedir (dp);
    }
  else
    perror ("Couldn't open the directory");
  return 0;
}
```

---

I finally located it. There are seveal "include" folders in the directories. If anyone cares it differs from the GNU GCC and is below. Why `d_type` is omitted, I don't know.

```
struct dirent
{
    long            d_ino;      /* Always zero. */
    unsigned short  d_reclen;   /* Always zero. */
    unsigned short  d_namlen;   /* Length of name in d_name. */
    char            d_name[260]; /* [FILENAME_MAX] */ /* File name. */
};

/*
 * This is an internal data structure. Good programmers will not use it
 * except as an argument to one of the functions below.
 */
```

Comment: Did you look in `dirent.h`? https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirent.h.html `d_type` may be specific to glibc. https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Took me awhile to find it.

Comment: When you cannot find documentation on the functions declared in `dirent.h`, your question should be “Where is documentation on the functions declared in `dirent.h`?”, not how to go poking about the header files or extracting member information from the compiler. Documentation tells you proper and supported ways to access things. Header files may reveal current implementation details (and may be educational; I am not saying not to analyze them) but are not reliable for writing supported software.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't ask that because I don't think there is any documentation. The links on minGW-W64 go to source forge and most titles have nothing. Do you happen to know where documentation specific to minGW-W64 can be found? I agree; that would be most useful to me.

Comment: You can self answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to see the contents of a header file as the compiler sees it is `gcc -E file.c > file.i` where `file.c` contains only the `#include` line for the header file.

This will expand all macros thereof and generally result in a really long output, but in this case it would have served you well. The struct definition would be in the output.

Thankfully these days the authors have enough sense to use `typedef` rather than `#define` for all the custom types. This wasn't always the case and this used to be a lot less readable than it is now.

As for `d_type` it's not standardized, just added by Linux. So I'm not surprised much the Windows emulation doesn't have it.